# Run ruby scripts from php ignoring output

Tags: php, ruby

I have to run in background a shell command (that uses a ruby script from /usr/local/bin) using php (from a html/php form) and ignoring all the output.
I've tried unsuccessfully `exec()`, `system()`, `shell_exec()`.

Also executing the script (not written by me, [script link](https://github.com/inket/RubyXDCCGetter/blob/master/xdcc.rb)  - I don't know ruby) in the terminal and redirecting the standard output to /dev/null, it keeps showing real-time infos about the download progress and speed of the download until it's completed.

I suppose it's because of the script and I've read somewhere that `proc_open()` can help but I don't know how to use it.

EDIT

Also adding "&" to the command (in the terminal) it keeps showing real-time infos about the download progress and speed of the download until it's completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/apache2/htdocs$ ls 
1.php   ruby_prog.rb
```

1.php:

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>
<?php

$command = 'ruby ruby_prog.rb';
$output = [];
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
echo($output[0]);

?>
</div>
```

ruby_prog.rb:

```
puts 'world'
```

url:

```
http://localhost:8181/1.php
```

output in browser:

```
hello
world
```

source html:

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>
world</div>
```

You can check the value of `$return_var`--if it's 0, then the ruby program ran successfully; if it's non-zero, there was an error.

If you don't want any output, then you can use the command:

```
ruby ruby_prog.rb > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `>` sends stdout to /dev/null, which is a *sink*, i.e. it acts like a blackhole, and `2>&1` says to send stderr(2) to wherever stdout(&1) goes.

Comment: It doesn't work...I only get the first line of output and the script doesn't continue the execution...Running the script in the terminal, the output is updated every second until the completion and then maybe this creates problems with the "background running" I need

Comment: @lebrac, *this creates problems with the "background running" I need* -- You said nothing about that in your question.

Comment: @lebrac, Add a space plus `&` to the end of the command--then exec() won't block.

Comment: you're right sorry...I've said "ignoring output" because usually redirecting the standard output to `/dev/null` allows me to run it in background...but not this time. Even adding `&`

Comment: @lebrac, That program looks like it has to do with illegal file sharing, so I'm out.

Comment: so xdcc protocol is illegal? Well i don't think that downloading subbed anime (actually a  lot of fansubbers use it - and also the example in the readme is about that kind of material) it is but thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: @lebrac, When I run the command in the Readme in a shell, I get: `'/Users/7stud/ruby_programs/Cerebrate/' is not a folder`.

Comment: in mine works well. Try: `./xdcc.rb irc.rizon.net Cerebrate 321 -c horriblesubs -d '/your/download/folder' `